# Convergence in $C(X,Y)$ with graph topology

Tags: general-topology

I can't figure out this point-set topology assertion. Suppose $X$ is paracompact (Hausdorff?) and $Y$ is metrizable with metric $d$. Then a basis of open sets for the graph topology $WO$ on $C(X,Y)$ (take this as the definition if you like) is given by open sets of the form $$U(f,\epsilon) := \{g \in C(X,Y) : d(f(x),g(x)) < \epsilon(x), \epsilon \in C(X,(0,\infty)).$$

The assertion is this:

> $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $WO$ iff there is a compact set $K$ such that
>   $f_n|_K \rightarrow f|_K$ uniformly and $f_n \equiv f$ off $K$ for all
>   but finitely many $n$.

Certainly the condition implies WO convergence, but I can't figure out how to get a converse. Convergence in WO implies that we get uniform convergence on for *any* subset, but I can't make sense of how to get the other part. The source asserts that we can choose a sequence of points $x_{n_k}$ with no cluster such that $f(x_{n_k}) \neq f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})$. From here, the result is clear enough since we can use a partition of unity to build an $\epsilon$ that makes a problem.

But how do we pick that sequence? If $X$ is [hemicompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicompact) then I can see how I might proceed, but otherwise I just don't know enough about the compact subsets of $X$. Can anyone who is better at point-set topology than me help out? The source of this statement is Michor's *Manifolds of Differentiable Mappings*, Lemma 3.4.

Comment: See page 43 of Golubitsky and Guillemin for a more thorough proof.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like this is false without an assumption on local compactness. Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Then $H$ is paracompact, and if we select a sequence of orthonormal vectors $e_n$, then we can construct functions $f_n$ which are positive on a ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ about $\frac{1}{n}e_n$ and zero elsewhere. Then this sequence of functions obviously can't satisfy the theorem, since a compact $K$ cannot have a subspace homeomorphic to an open ball in this Hilbert space. On the other hand, if $\epsilon$ is a positive function on $H$, then set $a = \epsilon(0)$ and $b$ to be the radious of some ball such that $\epsilon > \frac{a}{2}$ on a ball of that radius about $0$. If $\frac{1}{2n} < a,b$, then $f_n$ will be pointwise less than $\epsilon$, and so $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in the WO topology.

On the other hand, a local compactness assumption makes everything work out ok. Since I think the domains of interest are manifolds with corners in Michor, this should probably just be an added hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

@user-j

It is easy to check that Zach L.’s [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836578/convergence-in-cx-y-with-graph-topology/837621#837621) is OK.

Concerning your reference to [GG] (see the fragments from the pages [42](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSepq.png),  [43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUkjQ.png), [44](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XpDv.png)), there is written

> the sequence of mappings $f_n$ converge to $f$ (in the Whitney $C^k$ topology) iff there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $j^kf_n$ converges uniformly to $j^kf$ on $K$ and all but a finite number of the $f_n$'s equal $f$ off $K$. The "if" part is clear, and we shall prove the "only if" part by contradiction. Assume $f_n$ converges to $f$ and that there does not exist a compact set $K$ with the above property. Let $K_1, K_2,\dots$ be a sequence of compact subsets of $X$ such that $K_i\subset \operatorname{Int} (K_{i + 1})$ and $X =\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty K_i$.

For topological spaces the latter assumption is even stronger than hemicompactness. Indeed, according to exercise 3.4.E from [Eng] (referenced to [Are]):

> A Hausdorff space $X$ is *hemicompact* if in the family of all compact subspaces of $X$ ordered by $\subset$ there exists a countable cofinal subfamily.
>
> (a) Prove that every first-countable hemicompact space is locally compact.
>
> (b) Give an example of a countable hemicompact space which is not a $k$-space.
>
> (c) Show that in the realm of second-countable spaces hemicompactness is equivalent to local compactness.
>
> (d) Prove that if the space $\Bbb R^X$ with the compact-open topology is first-countable and $X$ is a Tychonoff space, then $X$ is hemicompact.

*References*

[Are] Arens R., *A topology for spaces of transformations*, Ann. Math. **47** (1946) 480-495.

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[GG] Martin Golubitsky, Victor Guillemin, *Stable Mappings and Their Singularities*, Springer-Verlag, 1973.

Comment: Zach L's answer addresses OP's source only at the end. OP is working with cornered manifolds and thus locally compact spaces, so I was looking to find out exactly how to construct the sequence of points, which seems to be OP's main underlying question.

Comment: @user-j So you ask for which Hausdorff paracompact non-hemicompact spaces $X$ fails the equivalence “$f_n \rightarrow f$ in $WO$ iff there is a compact set $K$ such that $f_n|_K \rightarrow f|_K$ uniformly and $f_n \equiv f$ off $K$ for all but finitely many $n$”?

Comment: Nope. Just want to know how to construct such a sequence $\{x_{n_k} \}$ as in OP's situation, ie working with cornered (or just regular) manifolds.

Comment: @user-j OK. In this case $X$ is necesarily non-compact. I expect when $X$ is locally compact hemicompact then we can easily adapt to it the construction from [GG, p. 43-44] which even  provides an example of a subsequence $\{f_{l_s}\}$ and a function $\delta$.

Comment: Yeah I was definitely hoping for another source though, I have tried to parse the proof/construction from [GG]. To be honest it seems to not be correct at all, either that or I am reading between the lines of their proof wrong. I guess I should just ask a separate question. (If no one comes along with a better answer I'll give you the bounty though)

Comment: @user-j I’m weak in manifold theory but I have some experience in general topology and I consider their construction natural and straightforward. So, if you need then I can try (a bit later) to adapt it to show the required implication for a locally compact hemicompact Hausdorff $X$.